# What is the expected time you have to wait until the first bus comes?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

 three buses, bus A, B, and C come to a bus stop every hour. The time at which each bus arrives at the stop is distributed as a uniform random variable, i.e., TA,TB,TC ∼ Unif[0,1] hours. The arrival times are independent, and the time or order at which they arrive is not known to you. You arrive at the bus stop at 12am. What is the expected time you have to wait until the first bus arrives?
Hint: calculate the probability that no bus has arrived at time t

I dont know how to get started. Can someone give me another hint?

Comment: Another hint: Measure time in hours, from $12:00$. The probability Bus A has arrived by time $t$ is $\frac{t}{1}$, so the probability it has **not** arrived is $1-t$. Similar considerations apply to the other two buses.

Comment: So the probability that no bus arrives at time t is (1-t)^3 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Now you need to continue. I suggest first finding the density function of the waiting time.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I think I got it.

Comment: You will want $\int_0^1 (t)(3)(1-t)^2\,dt$. Expand the square, and integrate term by term. It is a little (but not much) easier to let $u=1-t$.

Comment: What are those funky symbols I can't read?